# How can I get the center point of a polygon in MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, geometry, geom

I just called the ST_CENTROID(), MySQL 8 returns:

> [22001][3618] Data truncation: st_centroid(POLYGON) has not been implemented for geographic spatial reference systems.

I want get polygons from my db which should be within a circle, I use the function ST_Distance_Sphere() ，it needs two parameters both point so I need to get the polygon`s center point to complete it.

Comment: `ST_CENTROID()` still exists in [MySQL8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-polygon-property-functions.html#function_st-centroid).

Comment: Thanks , it seems like that you just said, But how can I get the center point？I just called the ST_CENTROID() ,MYSQL8 return "[22001][3618] Data truncation: st_centroid(POLYGON) has not been implemented for geographic spatial reference systems."

Comment: I've no idea, but that's a different question. I suggest you reword this to be specific about the problem you're having, since the basis of your original question is clearly wrong, but there is still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.

This is the workaround I found:

The following command didn't work:

```
st_centroid(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON("...."))
```

And this worked:

```
ST_Centroid(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON("..."))))
```